# Eclipse plugin - highlighting the file in the Package explorer (Project browser)

Tags: eclipse, select, plugins, treeview, highlight

I created a search function for finding a file in the Package explorer after name, therefore I know the path if the file exists. Now I want to be selected and highlighted the file (.java) from the Package explorer. 
So in a way it's opposite to handling the selection tree. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a structured selection object that can be understood by the view and then do the following

```
IViewReference[] views = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
for(IViewReference view:views){
    if("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer".equals(view.getId())){
        IViewPart pExplorer = view.getView(true);
        pExplorer.getViewSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection(selection);
        break;
    }
}
```